# Google+ box hiding on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus

Look at my code: http://codepen.io/lgarcia/pen/FwIne

Share box is working good.

When you hover on G+ to share something, writing box hides inmediately without having time to share anything. +1 Button is working, why this behavior? any help?

PS: I don't look to use a plugin or something, just need to fix my script.

Comment: i didnt saw anything wrong ..can u tell me exact error

Comment: click on +1 and wait to writing box to appear. Start writing and try to publish text. It's impossible.

Comment: `postmessage data invalid json:  SyntaxError {}` i got this error and repeatedly it is goin on

Comment: user1145009 i don't know what you mean

Comment: lucas garcia -- i saw those error in console ..

Comment: i don't think this error is the problem. In a normal configuration, the error appears as well. :-(